# appendChild or prepend causes SELECT item to re-sort

Tags: javascript

I have a SELECT box (generated by a WooCommerce variation) with some dates. Dates are not inserted by end users in the right order in WooCommerce back-end, so I need them to sort them accordingly.

I am using the following Javascript, but appending/prepending a "Select a date" option (which should be selected, causes them to lose the sort I gave them.

After the prepend the items are not sorted anymore (same with appendChild).

```js
// array functions are not working
// on nodeLists on IE, we need to
// to convert them to array
function toArray(obj) {
  var i, arr = [];
  for (i = obj.length; i--;) {
    arr[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return arr;
}
// custom compare function for sorting
// by the hidden date element
function sortByDate(el1, el2) {

  var a = convertToDate(el1.getAttribute("value")),
    b = convertToDate(el2.getAttribute("value"));

  if (a < b) return -1;
  else if (a > b) return 1;
  else return 0;

}

// convert date for string comparison
function convertToDate(date) {
  date = date.split("/");
  return date[2] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[0];
}

// select the elements to be ordered
var itemsId = document.getElementById("course-dates"),
  items = itemsId.getElementsByTagName("option"),
  len = items.length;

// convert to array, to make sorting possible
items = toArray(items);

// do the item sorting by their date
items = items.sort(sortByDate);

// append them back to the parent in order
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  itemsId.appendChild(items[i]);

  //adds a "select a date"                    
  // create new option element
  var opt = document.createElement('option');

  // create text node to add to option element (opt)
  opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Select a date'));

  // set value property of opt
  opt.value = 'option value';
  opt.selected = true
  // add opt to end of select box 
  itemsId.prepend(opt);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not sorted? Does the order change from what was in WooCommerce? My one suggestion would be to convert the dates from strings to Date objects and then sort based on that rather than the string representation where there can be subtle differences between numerical sort and alphanumerical sorts.

Comment: that's exaclty what the Javascript code does.In woocommerce dates are NOT inserted chronologically; my codes sorts them correctly but adding the "Select a date" option causes them to display "as inserted" in WooCommerce instead of sorted.chronologically. If I don't append the "Select a date" option, all dates are sorted correctly in a chronological order.